# What does the "?:^" regular expression mean?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking at this sub-expression (this is in JavaScript):

```
(?:^|.....)
```

I know that **?** means "zero or one times" when it follows a character, but not sure what it means in this context.

Comment: looks like an ambivalent Elvis with a pompadour... :p :D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're probably seeing it in this context

```
(?:...)
```

It means that the group won't be captured or used for back-references.

**EDIT:** To reflect your modified question:

```
(?:^|....)
```

means "match the beginning of the line or match ..." but don't capture the group or use it for back-references.

Comment: The caret is not part of the back reference expression.

Comment: @cynoclast: That's correct, but it was part of the question at the time of the answer (The question has since been modified)

Comment: Excellent - thank you. Unfortunately due to the characters in use, RegEx's are notoriously unsuited too googling :)

Answer (score 21):

When working with groups, you often have several options that modify the behavior of the group:

```
(foo)     // default behavior, matches "foo" and stores a back-reference
(?:foo)   // non-capturing group: matches "foo", but doesn't store a back-ref
(?i:foo)  // matches "foo" case-insensitively
(?=foo)   // matches "foo", but does not advance the current position
          // ("positive zero-width look-ahead assertion")
(?!foo)   // matches anything but "foo", and does not advance the position 
          // ("negative zero-width look-ahead assertion")
```

to name a few.

They all begin with "?", which is the way to indicate a group modifier. The question mark has nothing to do with optionality in this case.

It simply says:

```
(?:^foo)  // match "foo" at the start of the line, but do not store a back-ref
```

Sometimes it's just overkill to store a back-reference to some part of the match that you are not going to use anyway. When the group is there only to make a complex expression atomic (e.g. it should either match or fail as a whole), storing a back-reference is an unnecessary waste of resources that can even slow down the regex a bit. And sometimes, you just want to be group 1 the *first group relevant to you*, instead of the *first group in the regex*.

Answer (score 3):

`(?:some stuff)` means that you don't want to match the expression in the parentheses separately. Normally the pieces of a regexp grouped in parentheses are grouped and can be referenced individually (this is called using backreferences).

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Answer (score 3):

### Short Answer

It flags the (parenthetical) group as a [non-capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) group.

### Details About This Particular Expression

The notation for a non-capturing group is:

```
(?:<expresson>)
```

In the instance you presented, the caret (^) is part of the expression not part of the capturing group notation.  And this instance it's not a special character either.

It looks like they're using an 'or' operator (the pipe) with the caret.  So they're looking to match something that is a caret or whatever was on the right of the pipe, but not capture the expression as a group (accomplished with the `?:` in the beginning of the grouping characters.

### In General

Non-capturing groups allow you to group an expression in a way that won't be [back-refernceable](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), and will also increase performance of the expression.

Answer (score 2):

*"(?:x) Matches 'x' but does not remember the match."*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1):

?: Generally indicates making the group a non capture.  You can do some research [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html).

I'm almost positive any regex engine should but when I switch between engines I run into some quirks.

Edit: This should be the case, non captures seems to work fine.